# Why is this very simple cursor breaking SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

I have created an item on the Degree table and I want to duplicate that record for 19 other Colleges. I have a really simple cursor, but every time I run it it totally crashes SQL Server Management Studio. Is there a way to rewrite this query (or another query entirely which performs the same INSERT INTO) so that it does not crash (and actually executes)?

```
DECLARE @Colleges VARCHAR(200)

DECLARE DUPLICATE_DEGREE CURSOR FOR
SELECT CollegeID FROM Colleges WHERE CollegeName <> 'Main Office'
OPEN DUPLICATE_DEGREE 
FETCH NEXT FROM DUPLICATE_DEGREE INTO @Colleges

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Degree
(
  DegreeName
, CollegeID
)
SELECT
  DegreeName
, @Colleges
FROM Degrees
WHERE DegreeID = 123

END

CLOSE DUPLICATE_DEGREE 
DEALLOCATE DUPLICATE_DEGREE
```

Comment: Cursors aren't "simple" - there's seldom any reason to use a cursor in SQL, the language. In 99.999999999% of cases it results in orders of magnitude worse performance. SQL is a set-oriented language. Cursors are a legacy of file-based access

Comment: As for crashing SSMS, I doubt it. SSMS is a client tool, not the database itself. If the script seems to freeze, it's probably because the cursor either blocked itself, or ended up in an infinite loop. It would be a **lot** easier to write an `INSERT INTO Degree(DegreeName,CollegeID) SELECT DegreeName,CollegeID from Collegees,Degree where DegreeID=123 and CollegeName !='Main Office'`

Comment: Jake, please edit your post and explain overall what needs to be done. **"...I have created an item on the Degree table and I want to duplicate that record for 19 other Colleges..."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is getting stuck in an infinite loop because you're never advancing the cursor and therefore the value of `@@FETCH_STATUS` never changes resulting in you adding the same record for the same college ad nauseum.  Add `FETCH NEXT FROM DUPLICATE_DEGREE INTO @Colleges` after the `INSERT`.

Comment: That did it... can't believe I forgot that, but I rarely have to loop through a cursor. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Jake - you don't need a cursor, try this:

```
DECLARE @DegreeName varchar (256)
SET @DegreeName = SELECT DISTINCT DegreeName from Degrees WHERE DegreeID = 123

INSERT INTO Degree (DegreeName, CollegeID) 
   SELECT @DegreeName, CollegeID 
   FROM Colleges WHERE CollegeName <> 'Main Office'
```